# Python Slicing and conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements, slice

I need to write code that can find the middle three characters of a string and print them. If the string is even in length, it would just print the middle two.
If the string is too short, it would print the entire string.

I wrote the following but I get odd results for shorter characters, like the letter "a" for example.

```
   text = input("Type your word: ")
   length = len(text)
   center = int(length / 2)
   print("3 middle letters: ", text[center-1:center+2])

   if length % 2 == 0:
       print("2 middle letters: ", text[center-1:center+1])
   if length <= 1:
       print("")
```

Examples of output:

1. "a" > too short, print the whole string
2. "an" > even, return both characters
3. "can" > odd, return middle three
4. "cant" > even, return "an"
5. "canters" > return middle three, "nte"
6. "cant err" > return middle two, "t "

Comment: Take a look at [this advice on debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), in particular the part about the [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging): Try to explain in your own words what your code is doing line by line, and see if you can find were the logic fails. Cue: try a word with two characters.

Comment: Your code says `if length <= 1: print("")`. If I read that aloud, it doesn't sound like what you want in the first example of your output.

Comment: `length // 2` (_floor division_) will give you the same result as `int(length / 2)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I wrote the following but I get odd results for shorter characters, like the letter "a" for example." What's strange about the result? And **what is your question** about it? Did you consider writing code to handle this case specially? Please try to think about the logic of the program, and carefully [check what actually happens, step by step](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), compared to your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to review the if statement.

```
text = input("Type your word: ")
length = len(text)
center = int(length / 2)

if length > 2:
    print("3 middle letters: ", text[center-1:center+2])
elif length == 2:
    print("2 middle letters: ", text[center-1:center+1])
else:
    print("")
```

Comment: I added the expected results above Kim if that could clarify things :)

Comment: "I added the expected results above" Okay, and when you try this code, what happens, and **how is that different** from the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input("Type your word: ")
length = len(text)
center = length // 2

print(text[center-1:center+1+length % 2])
```

Note that `length // 2` is the same as `int(length / 2)`.